# Typescript compiler not converting "this" into "_this"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, compiler-errors, tsconfig

Below are the methods in my TypeScript class:

```
downloadIpFlowInfo() {
    this.loading = false;
    this.ipFlowLogRequestRestResourceApi.registerDownloadLogDataRequest().then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}

checkAutoDisable() {
        this.autoDisable = setInterval(() => {
            return this.ipFlowLogRequestRestResourceApi.getRequestStatus(this.r6CurrentTenant, this.subscriptionId).then((response) => {
               ....
               .....
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
```

When compiling `downloadIpFlowInfo` method it is not converting "this" to "_this" while some other methods are  converting. See the screenshot below:

[image]

The issue I'm getting is that when I'm calling `this.ipFlowLogRequestRestResourceApi.registerDownloadLogDataRequest()` it is throwing below error

`JavaScript error: this.ipFlowLogRequestRestResourceApi.registerDownloadLogDataRequest is not a function`

While calling other methods are working fine.

Comment: How does `checkAutoDisable` look in source code?

Comment: @Cerberus: it is same as above. I'm updating the post

Comment: @Cerberus: See the updated posts. There are lot of methods in the class but issue is only in that method.

Comment: `downloadIpFlowInfo` doesn't **need** `_this` because `this` isn't used in any function callbacks - is there a problem with the code because there's no `_this` in that function?

Comment: @Bravo: It is the typescript compiler which is adding _this in every function

Comment: yes, in every function it's **actually required in**, and it isn't in `downloadIpFlowInfo`  ... the error is that `this.ipFlowLogRequestRestResourceApi.registerDownloadLogDataRequest` is not a function, which has nothing to do with the lack of `var _this = this`, since `this` is clearly not undefined, and `this.ipFlowLogRequestRestResourceApi` is not undefined since the error is that `this.ipFlowLogRequestRestResourceApi.registerDownloadLogDataRequest` is not a function - so it's either undefined, or something that isn't a function ... what should it be?

Comment: what you need to concentrate on, rather than `_this` is what do you define `registerDownloadLogDataRequest` to be (assuming its some code you wrote) check for typos - in other words, what is `this.ipFlowLogRequestRestResourceApi` ... does it have a method named exactly `registerDownloadLogDataRequest`

Comment: `registerDownloadLogDataRequest ` is a function and there are several other functions are there in `ipFlowLogRequestRestResourceApi` class.

Comment: OK, here's how to force the compiler to create it `console.log(response, this.loading)` - that should fix the problem you see - but it won't fix the problem you have

Comment: okay. let me try